# SwiftUI Magnification Gestures on View

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to have gestures such as Magnification Gestures on a View. I would like to do this so I can scale multiple items at once.

I wrote the following, but the gesture never gets called on the View. Although it works on many other objects like text, images, colorsquares . . .

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var newScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        TestView1()
            .scaleEffect(newScale)
            .gesture (
                MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        self.newScale = gesture
                    }
            )
    }
    
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: See [this article from *iOS Creator*](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/swiftui-magnification-gesture-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code from the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/magnificationgesture).

```swift
struct MagnificationGestureView: View {

    @GestureState var magnifyBy = 1.0

    var magnification: some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .updating($magnifyBy) { currentState, gestureState, transaction in
                gestureState = currentState
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        TestViewOne()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .scaleEffect(magnifyBy)
            .gesture(magnification)
    }
}
```

I think the `.updating` modifier is key here. Docs for that: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gesture/updating(_:body:)/. Once again, this code is a slight modification of the code on the Apple Docs. Link here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/magnificationgesture.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the `.updating` doesn't save the zoom like the `.onchange` which is why I'm using `.onchange`. It looks like my issue is I have gestures within my View, I removed those and got it working :)